# What is the correct way to write a typescript method that expects a Promise but can return nothing if conditions aren't met?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, promise

Ok lets say I have a method as follows:

```
getSomethingImportant() : ng.IPromise<any> {
    if (!conditionsMet) { return; }
    return someApi.thatReturns.aPromise().then((response) => {
        // Normal stuff here
    });
}
```

Typescript gives a warning because return isn't returning anything, but thats because I want it to not run if the conditions aren't met (missing arguments or already running or whatever).

Should I create a promise and return it right away?

Should I ignore the error?

Change the return type?

Comment: From an API design perspective it's probably better to always return a promise.

Comment: @FelixKling what would be the best object to return then? A failure? I could throw an error, but then something would **have** to call it and wait or it could go "unhandled" and potentially break everything.

Comment: you might also consider if the error is exceptional in nature that you `throw new Error("Think of the conditions!");` rather than returning a `reject`ed promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `null`-resolved promise and return it right away:

```
if (!conditionsMet) {
    return $q.when(null); 
}
```

Or you you perceive the situation when the conditions are not met as an error, you can return a rejected promise:

```
if (!conditionsMet) {
    return $q.reject(new Error('Conditions have not been met...')); 
}
```

Comment: return $q.reject(new Error('Conditions have not been met...')); -- perfect thanks! It lets me pass the error back without killing if called direct

Answer (score 2):

Function that returns a promise must never return anything else nor throw an exception. If you want to return something, return a promise resolved with the value you want to return and if you want to throw something, return a promise rejected with the error you want to throw.

Otherwise you are making the function extremely awkward to use.